# Why is this program showing a runtime error on this input?

Tags: c++, runtime-error

I am getting runtime error for 3rd input from this problem on uva. I don't know where my code is breaking.

https://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=onlinejudge&page=show_problem&problem=349

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    long int  step,mod,i=0,temp;
    cin >> step >> mod;
    int count[mod+1] = {0};
    count[0] = 1;
    vector<int> seed;
    seed.push_back(0);
    while(true)
    {
        seed[i+1] = (seed[i]%mod + step%mod)%mod;
        temp = seed[i+1];
        if(temp == 0)
        {
            break;
        }
        count[temp] +=  1;
        ++i;
    }
    bool flag = true;
    for(int i=0; i<mod; i++)
    {
        if(count[i] <= 0)
            {
                flag = 0;
                break;
            }
    }
    if(flag)
        cout << "Numbers have been generated\n";
    else
        cout << "Wrong choice\n";
    return 0;
}
```

The answer should be "good choice" i.e output should be `Numbers have been generated` on my program but it's showing a runtime error.

Comment: `i` increases but the size of your vector that is indexed by it does not.

Comment: In fact, on the very first iteration, `seed` has size 1 so `seed[0]` is the only valid index. Yet you access `seed[i+1]` that is `seed[1]`. Your program exhibits undefined behavior, by way of accessing index out of bounds.

Comment: `int count[mod+1] = {0};` -- This is not valid C++.  Arrays in C++ must have their sizes denoted by a constant expression, not a runtime computed value like `mod + 1`.  You're using `vector` already in your program, so you should be using it here: `std::vector<int> count(mod + 1);`.